# Create a generic method that used JPA2 and CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

I'm developing a web application that use JSF2 and JPA2 frameworks.
I started using the wizards on netbeans7.0 and the "New JSF Pages from Entity Classes" created a classAbstractFacade" contains this useful method:

```
public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
  javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
  cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
  javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
  q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0]);
  q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
  return q.getResultList();
}
```

where T is the entity class that contains the database structure of the table, and the range variable contains two number for retrieve a sublist of the results!
Now I modify it to set an order by clause and check if user a range or not and the new code is:

```
    public List<T> findRangeOrdered(int[] range, String orderBy) {
      javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<T> cq = (javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<T>)getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
      cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
      javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> r = cq.from(entityClass);
      if(orderBy!=null && !orderBy.equals("")){
        if(orderBy.ebdsWith(" desc"))
          cq.orderBy(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().desc(r.get(orderBy.substring(0,orderBy.indexOf(" ")))));
        else
          cq.orderBy(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().desc(r.get(orderBy.substring(0,orderBy.indexOf(" ")))));
      }
      javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
      if(range!=null)
      {
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0]);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
      }
      return q.getResultList();
    }
```

Now I would add some where options.
I'm thinking about adding a List variable that could contains an HashMap with these couple of key--> value:

- "type" --> the type of the field that I would search (for example String.class or java.util.Date.class);
- "name" --> the name of the field on the entity class;
- "value0" --> the first value that I would looking for;
- "value1" --> the second value for the "between" clause;
- "clause" --> which filter I want use.

Now I have some doubts:

1) is this idea a good idea?

2) do a framework exit that already implements thisfunction?

3) if the answer at the previous questions are: Yes it's a good idea; and No, there isn't any framework that already do it, I find these new problems:
this new method returns me some compiler errors:

```
public List<T> findAllFiltered(int[] range, String orderBy, List<HashMap<String,Object>> whereList) {
  List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
  String buf;
  HashMap<String,Object> where;
  int i=0;
  javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<T> cq = (javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<T>)getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
  cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
  javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> r = cq.from(entityClass);
  javax.persistence.criteria.Path<T> path = cq.from(entityClass);
  if(whereList!= null && whereList.size()>0){
    Iterator iter=whereList.iterator();
    Predicate p;
    while (iter.hasNext())    
    {
      where=(HashMap<String,Object>)iter.next();

      if(where.get("where").toString().equals("like"))
        p = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().like(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().upper(r.<String>get(where.get("name").toString())), "%"+where.get("value0").toString().toUpperCase()+"%");
      else if(where.get("where").toString().equals("equal"))
        p = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().equal(r.get(where.get("name").toString()), where.get("value0").toString());
      else if(where.get("where").toString().equals("in"))
        p = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().and(r.get(where.get("name").toString()).in(where.get("value0").toString().replaceAll("#",",")));
      else if(where.get("where").toString().equals("between"))
      {
        java.util.Date value0=(java.util.Date)where.get("value0");
        java.util.Date value1=(java.util.Date)where.get("value1");
        p = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().between(r.<java.util.Date>get(where.get("name").toString()),value0,value1);
      }
      else if(where.get("where").toString().equals("greatest"))
        p = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().and(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().greatest(r.<Long>get(where.get("name").toString())));
      else if(where.get("where").toString().equals("greaterThanOrEqualTo"))
      {
        java.util.Date value0=(java.util.Date)where.get("value0");
        p = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().greaterThanOrEqualTo(r.<java.util.Date>get(where.get("name").toString()),value0);
      }
      else if(where.get("where").toString().equals("lessThanOrEqualTo"))
      {
        java.util.Date value0=(java.util.Date)where.get("value0");
        p = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().lessThanOrEqualTo(r.<java.util.Date>get(where.get("name").toString()),value0);
      }

    }
  }
  Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[predicateList.size()];
  predicateList.toArray(predicates);
  cq.where(predicates);

  if(orderBy!= null&& !orderBy.equals("")){
    if(orderBy.endsWith("desc"))
      cq.orderBy(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().desc(r.get(orderBy.substring(0,orderBy.indexOf(" ")))));
    else
      cq.orderBy(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().asc(r.get(orderBy.substring(0,orderBy.indexOf(" ")))));
  }

  javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
  if(range!=null){
    q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0]);
    q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
  }
  return q.getResultList();
}
```

1) The "greatest" method returns this error:

```
p = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().and(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().greatest(r.<Long>get(where.get("name").toString())));
method CriteriaBuilder.and(Expression<Boolean>,Expression<Boolean>) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method CriteriaBuilder.and(Predicate...) is not applicable
(argument type Expression<Long> does not conform to vararg element type Predicate)
```

and I search about an example for this method but I didn't find anything of useful;

2) as I wrote, my HashMapp contains also the class of field that I want filter, now I would use this information for rewrite the between, greaterThanOrEqualTo, lessThanOrEqualTo so, if I would, I can filter some other types than java.util.Date!
What do you think about this long question?
Thank you for your help!

P.S.: Sorry for my not perfect english but I'm italian.

P.S.2: Sorry, also, for the structure of my code... I'm blind and I dont' control all times the indentation... this site control it but I'm not sure that I indent all code correctly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, it's not a good idea. You're reinventing a new generic query language, and this new query language will be

- less expressive than JPQL
- nonstandard
- less type-safe than the Criteria API
- less efficient than JPQL and Criteria

So the answers to your questions are

1. No, it's not a good idea
2. Yes, such a framework already exists. It's called JPQL.

Comment: @ jb-nizet: so you suggest to pass a String that contains the query that I want execute?

Comment: No. I suggest defining an ad-hoc business service method with specific arguments, a clear contract and a javadoc, and execute the appropriate specific HQL or Criteria query from this service. The presentation layer should not have to deal with queries. It should call specific services with a well-defined contract and interface, and these services should deal with the queries.

Comment: Sorry jb-nizet but I don't understand what you mean... 
Are you speaking about something like: table1Query class contains more method to do query for the fields contain in table1, table2Query class contain all method to filter table2 ecc?
If it isn't right, can you write a simple practical example or link one example?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: The JSF controllers should not execute queries directly. They should call business services. For example, the customer search page could use a CustomerManager service, and this service would have methods like findCustomersByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName), createCustomer(Customer customer). Those methods will be the ones that will be transactional, use the JPA api and execute queries, but also contain business logic such as "when a customer is created, a mail must be sent to some administrator". No need for any generic searchAnything(SearchCriteria) method.

Comment: Ok, I will do such method! Thanks again for your help!
P.S.: When I will have 15 rep points I will give you an UP vote...

Comment: You should probably read up on Data Access Object patterns and similar patterns for doing data access.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think create a method that use string for build query with the Criteria API is a good idea, I definitely suggest to use JPQL or if you prefer some other tool that help you to build query in a smartest way, you can use: [ObjectQuery](http://objectquery.org) or [Query Dsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) or [Torpedo Query](http://torpedoquery.org/),  if you want isolate your code to the actual implementation think to hide the query inside some DAO or Repository object, or at least create a wrapper over some query builder!